# Laravel Auth not working after moving to remove

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authentication

I have moved my local laravel Application to Production. On my local pc the register function work's well (using Laravel Auth). On the remote host nothing happeds when I submit the register form. No validation error or something else. What is wrong with my application?

[image]

I got an 404 while the process. Here my register routes:

```
Route::get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
```

Here the content of my register.blade.php file:

```
<form id="js-validation-signup" action="{{ route('register') }}" method="post">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="py-3">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text"
                                       class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-alt{{ $errors->has('first_name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
                                       id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="{{ __('First Name') }}"
                                       value="{{ old('first_name') }}" autocomplete="off">
                                @if ($errors->has('first_name'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('first_name') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text"
                                       class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-alt{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
                                       id="name" name="name" placeholder="{{ __('Name') }}"
                                       value="{{ old('name') }}" autocomplete="off">
                                @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email"
                                       class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-alt{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
                                       id="email" name="email" placeholder="{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}"
                                       autocomplete="off" value="{{ old('email') }}">
                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="password"
                                       class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-alt{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
                                       id="password" name="password" placeholder="{{ __('Password') }}">
                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-alt"
                                       id="password_confirmation" name="password_confirmation"
                                       placeholder="{{ __('Confirm Password') }}">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-alt{{ $errors->has('application_name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
                                           id="application_name"
                                           name="application_name" type="text"
                                           placeholder="{{ __('Application Name') }}" autocomplete="off"
                                           value="{{ old('application_name')  }}">
                                    <div class="input-group-append">
                                        <span class="input-group-text input-group-text-alt">.example.com</span>
                                    </div>
                                    @if ($errors->has('application_name'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('application_name') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-primary">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="signup-terms"
                                           name="signup-terms">
                                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="signup-terms">I agree to Terms &amp;
                                        Conditions</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-hero-lg btn-hero-primary">
                                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-user-plus mr-1"></i> Sign Up
                            </button>
                            <p class="mt-3 mb-0 d-lg-flex justify-content-lg-between">
                                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-light d-block d-lg-inline-block mb-1" href="#">
                                    <i class="fa fa-book text-muted mr-1"></i> Read Terms
                                </a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: did u check at the network tab of the console?

Comment: I've edited the question.

Comment: Please share your corresponding .blade files

Comment: I've added the content :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i had the same problem with `login` here.

my problem was that I used Laravel's auth login and inside `Auth/LoginController` has a
`use AuthenticatesUsers` which uses a trait that is inside vendor and Auth folder and when I wanted to use git clone to get the project on another computer and used `composer install` to install the used packages for the project my vendor changed to default and all the login code which was in AuthenticatesUsers trait removed and changed to default

Answer (score 0):

The *route()* function is for named routes.
It seems that you named your get route but didn't do that with the corresponding post route. Accessing *route('register')* with a POST method will result in a 404 error.
Try to name the post route as well or use *action('Auth\RegisterController@register')*

```
<form id="js-validation-signup" action="{{action('Auth\RegisterController@register')}}" method="post">
```